# Using custom name of `name` field of Zizaco/entrust Package

Tags: laravel-5, user-permissions, user-roles

I am working in a project that has a large postgreSQL database. The previous project was developed in Java from scratch. We are now developing that in Laravel. The previous system had `user management` system similar to `Zizaco/entrust`. So, we used in our system as well. The previous table had `module` table instead of `permission` table used in `entrust`. We have already configured that by changing the table name in `config/entrust.php`. However, the previous system has `permission_name` instead of `name` field used in `entrust`. How do I config `entrust` to use the unique `permission_name` instead of `name` field.

I am looking for a solution, so that we don't have to change in the `sources` of `entrust` because then upgrading it would break the system. Can it be configured in the model?

Answer (score 1):

The Entrust package is hardcoded to use the `name` attribute, so there is no configuration value or anything to change that. However, one thing you can attempt is to define an accessor and mutator for the `name` attribute.

In your `App\Permission` model, define the following functions:

```
class Permission extends Model {
    // accessor
    public function getNameAttribute($value) {
        return $this->permission_name;
    }

    // mutator
    public function setNameAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['permission_name'] = $value;
    }
}
```

Documentation for accessors and mutators: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators